# Obj C - Google Cardboard pause video not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cardboard

I have implemented the Google Cardboard/VRView SDK into my project and am trying to load the video so that it is paused when the app first loads.

However despite setting the `_isPaused` variable to `YES`/`TRUE` it doesn't appear to work and the video plays automatically when the view controller is loaded.

Anyone used this before?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NewViewController.h"
#import "GCSVideoView.h"


@interface NewViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet GCSVideoView *viewView;



@end

@implementation NewViewController {
    BOOL _isPaused;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _viewView.enableFullscreenButton = YES;
    _viewView.enableCardboardButton = NO;

    _isPaused = YES;

    // Load the sample 360 video, which is of type stereo-over-under.
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    [_viewView loadFromUrl:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
}



#pragma mark - GVRVideoViewDelegate

- (void)widgetViewDidTap:(GCSWidgetView *)widgetView {
    if (_isPaused) {
        [_viewView resume];
    } else {
        [_viewView pause];
    }
    _isPaused = !_isPaused;
}

- (void)widgetView:(GCSWidgetView *)widgetView didLoadContent:(id)content {
    NSLog(@"Finished loading video");
}

- (void)widgetView:(GCSWidgetView *)widgetView
didFailToLoadContent:(id)content
  withErrorMessage:(NSString *)errorMessage {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load video: %@", errorMessage);
}

- (void)videoView:(GCSVideoView*)videoView didUpdatePosition:(NSTimeInterval)position {
    // Loop the video when it reaches the end.
    if (position == videoView.duration) {
        [videoView seekTo:0];
        [videoView resume];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: After `loadFromUrl:`, try `[viewView pause];`?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)widgetView:(GVRWidgetView *)widgetView didLoadContent:(id)content {
    NSLog(@"Finished loading video");
    [self.videoView pause];
    self.isPaused = YES;
}
```

Try adding this to your didLoadContent delegate method. This will ensure the video is paused once it's loaded.